# Как можно создать документ на python?

Tags: python, html, математика, latex

Я делаю программу которая генерирует уникальные для каждого студента экзаменационные задачи. Проблема возникает когда надо это все на бумаге распечатать. Как я могу через python создавать документ на котором будут задачи которые сгенерировал? Есть что-то кроме html и latex?

Comment: Простите, а чем вам не угодили html и latex?

Comment: Можете docx создавать https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Можно сгенерированные формулы сохранять, как картинку.

Прилагаю пример кода:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = random.randint(2, 4)
c = random.randint(2, 4)
n = random.randint(2, 4)

x = b**c-n
formula = f'$\log_{b}(x+{n}) = {c}$'

xsize = 5
ysize = 1.5
plt.figure(figsize=(xsize, ysize))
plt.text(0.0, 0, formula, fontsize=35)
# Прячем оси
plt.axis('off')
    
plt.savefig('filename.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: Правильный импорт `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, а как у вас ошибка будет.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю то, что вы ищете это [PyFPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ/index.html). Подойдет PDF для печати?

Что умеет:

1. Различные шрифты
2. Настройка страниц (портрет, ландшафт, А4, А5, письмо и тд)
3. Вставка картинок
4. Стилизация и кастомизация футеров, хедеров
5. Графики (просто `plot` можно отправить), картинки
6. Работа с [HTML](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html). То есть просто можете вставить ваш HTML в тройные кавычки и все должно получиться. Только не забывайте о поддержке тегов, все есть в документации. Например, тег `<img>` поддерживается вместе с атрибутами размеров и источником
7. и многое другое

А для более детальных разборов, приведите примеры ваших билетов.